# Python-3 : Check if a subnet is available

Tags: python-3.x, subnet

I am writing a code in python-3 where I need to create a subnet with the input given by the user. As a part of validation, I need to check if the given subnet overlaps with any other existing subnets. I know we can check if two given subnets overlap or not, but how do we check for the above mentioned problem?

Comment: Load all configured subnets and check them one at a time?

Comment: How to load all those subnets?

Comment: I'd personally just shell out to the `route` system command and parse the output (bearing in mind it will be different on windows and linux), but there may be  a better way using the python libraries

Comment: You don't get the subnets in route command, right?

Comment: You do on the linux box I just tested which is Centos 7 (`route`) and Windows 10 (`route print`). Don't have anything else to hand to test readily.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu and it's not showing any subnet related info

Comment: The Ubuntu manual says it should be there, under a heading of "Genmask": http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/route.8.html ... `Genmask:
              The netmask for the destination  net;  '255.255.255.255'  for  a
              host destination and '0.0.0.0' for the default route.`

Comment: We have to calculate the subnet using the genmask, right?

Comment: genmask == subnet mask (genmask is generic network mask).  Ignore 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 and you have all subnets configured on the current machine. No calculation required.

Comment: Also... I've just found this library which may achieve the same... https://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/